# Use the improper prior $p(v) \propto 1/v$ into Jags

Tags: bayesian, prior, jags

I know that one can approximate this density ($p(v) \propto 1/v$) using its truncated version and implement it this way:

```
   B~dunif(log(BInf),log(BSup))
   v<-exp(B)
```

but I would like to use the exact form (I checked that under this prior my posterior is proper). Is there any solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe JAGS does not allow [improper priors](http://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/33bc5520#d882). So your suggested approach is as close as you can get.